# Converting filebound file data to string in ASP.NET C#

Tags: asp.net

I have FileBound Functionality from where I uplaod and download files.
When I click on any download link, the file gets downloaded to downloaded folder. The downloaded file is not by default in docx format. When I click on this file to opn, it asks for the format and after selecting Microsoft Word the file gets open. I am using below code for this:

```
**DMS.Model.Document document = _documentManagement.RetrieveFile(documentId);**

------------------------------------------------------------------

**if (document != null)**
**{**
fileName = document.FileName;
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
document.FileData.CopyTo(stream);
data = stream.ToArray();
}
}

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName) && data.Length > 0)
{
if (fileName.IndexOf(".doc") > 0)
{
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileInfo.Name);
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", data.Length.ToString());
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document";
}
else if (fileName.IndexOf(".pdf") > 0)
{
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
}
else
{
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileInfo.Name);
}

Response.OutputStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
}
```

---

But now I want to display the content of this file in a rich textbox or in a div container.

I have already tried:

```
byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(String.Format(formatString, strings) + Environment.NewLine);

StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(document.FileData);
string str = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

I have tried every possible thing but with no luck.
"Here document.FileData is of type MemoryStream"